# Google sheets IF chained VLOOKUP statements on #N/A not working?

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I'm trying to use IF statements to execute multiple vlookups, with the goal of searching multiple ranges in sequence for a single search key if the key is not found in the first range.

This is premised on the output of a Vlookup when the key is not found being "#N/A", and triggering the second vlookup when that is the output from the first range. My code:

`=if(vlookup(A6,Range1!A:A,1,false)<>#N/A,"Match",if(vlookup(A6,Range2!A:A,1,false)<>#N/A,"Match",if(vlookup(A6,Range3!A:A,1,false)<>#N/A,"Match",if(vlookup(A6,Range4!A:A,1,false)<>#N/A,"Match",if(vlookup(A6,Range5!A:A,1,false)<>#N/A,"Match","Not")))))`

What I was expecting is for the lookup to proceed through the ranges if an output of #N/A is found, ultimately resulting in each search key being assigned "Match" or "Not". What is happening is that the second If statement is not executing, and my outputs are either "Match" or "#N/A".

Answer (score 0):

try this out:

`=if(NOT(ISERROR(vlookup(A6,Range1!B:B,1,false))),"Match",if(NOT(ISERROR(vlookup(A6,Range2!B:B,1,false))),"Match",if(NOT(ISERROR(vlookup(A6,Range3!B:B,1,false))),"Match",if(NOT(ISERROR(vlookup(A6,Range4!B:B,1,false))),"Match",if(NOT(ISERROR(vlookup(A6,Range5!B:B,1,false))),"Match","Not")))))`

Answer (score 0):

I think this is a more compact representation that achieves the same result:

```
=arrayformula(if(sum(n(A6={Range1!B:B;Range1!B:B;Range3!B:B;Range3!B:B;Range4!B:B;Range5!B:B;Range6!B:B}))>=1,"Match","Not"))
```

The VLOOKUPs are not needed (as you're just looking for a match in a list rather than actually doing a lookup here), and you can union all the ranges together to eliminate a lot of unnecessary nesting.

Comment: Interested to try this. What does the "n" do in the part of the formula if(sum(n(A6

Comment: The output of the array comparing A6 to the unioned ranges is a column of TRUEs and FALSEs. N coerces these into 1s & 0s so that the array can be summed. If the sum >=1 then there was >=1 TRUE (implying >=1 match), if the sum is zero then there were no matches.